I cannot find the anode rod in a water tank. Pressure release value is on top
I didn't replace the anode rod over 10 years.
Tried to find to anode rod bolt but cannot reach to it from the top.
I used drill and removed insulation foam 10 inches deep, but is not touching anything solid. Should I dig deeper into it? I think I can drill 2 more inches.
It looks like I am digging a wrong hole, the anode rod may under pressure release valve. But I am not sure if I can remove it as it is connected to another pipe that I don't know where it goes.




Have you looked for the manufacturers web site.

You're probably driling in the foam fill hole. You should check the manual for your water heater for the location of the anode rod (in some cases it's combined with the dip tube. Most of the time its separate.)

https://assets.hotwater.com/damroot/Original/10004/GNR-40%20instruction%20manual.pdf

A google search gave me this:  https://www.aosmithatlowes.com/media/1683/signature-100-series-standard-electric-100341465.pdf which may or may not be right, but it shows the anode in the middle back (next to last page).

I think the anode rod is under the hot water pipe or the pressure release valve. Both are not easy to access. I decided to use the other pressure release valve on the side and add another anode rod there. I think having 2 anode rods would not harmful to the tank.
